tengo un problema con mi base de datos en SQLite3, no me lee los archivos que tengo dentro, segun yo, ya cree el dataframe de pandas
import pandas as pd

ruta_archivo = 'datosfebrero.xlsx'
nombre_hoja = 'FEBRERO2024'

datos = pd.read_excel(ruta_archivo, sheet_name=nombre_hoja)

print(datos.head())


#el segundo de SQLite3 seria esta linea de codigo

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mi_base_de_datos.db')

datos.to_sql('nombre_de_tabla', engine, index=False)

ahora quiero que en el sqlite me muestre los valores que tengo en el excel que cree aparte y que por eso puse "nombre_archivo" para que me abra ese excel pero no me lee nada de los datos solo me sale "datos.to_sql" datos is not defined

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Las preguntas que tienen solo código tienden a considerarse de mala calidad, suelen recibir votos negativos y terminar cerradas por la comunidad. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] y agregar una explicación de lo que buscas y no hace el código, o si genera un error, la información del mismo, así como el o los mensajes exactos de error y el momento en el que se producen (al compilar, al ejecutar, en tal línea, si se introduce un dato u otro, etc.  Encontrarás más información en [ask]. Un saludo.

esto pasaría solo si no tienes todo en un solo script sino en dos distintos, pues defines datos en la cuarta línea. Mi sugerencia es que ejecutes todo como un único script. Saludos.

hola intente hacerlo asi en solo script pero aun asi me tira error en "datos is not defined"

qué línea es la que genera ese error?

en "datos.to_sql" en mi caso seria la linea 7

Pues, en la línea del print() si que está definido entonces, lo único que se me ocurre es que el import pueda limpiar el espacio de variables, cosa que me parece rara, pero no soy experto. Prueba mover el segundo import a la segunda línea, que además haría mucho más sentido que estén todos al inicio, a ver si eso hace la diferencia.

tampoco funciono :c, la verdad no se que sea

ahora que releo tu pregunta, veo que no es datos el que no está definido, sino datos.to_sql. ¿Qué salida produce print(type(datos)) justo después de la llamada a read_excel()? ¿Qué versión de pandas estás usando?
